# c# How can I get the nameof the item list referred to?

Tags: c#

is it possible to get the `nameof` a variable when its referred to as a list index? The first line in my RUN() method compiles and produces the "x", the second line will not compile, saying the expression does not have a name. But it does have a name - how can I direct it during runtime to get that name, or is this impossible via lists?

```
    class list_experiment
    {
        public string x = "xx";
        public List<string> list;

        public list_experiment()
        {
            list = new List<string>() { x };
        }
    }


    static public void RUN()
    {
        list_experiment a = new list_experiment();

        Console.WriteLine(nameof(a.x));
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(a.list[0])); // Doesn't compile
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to capture the name of that variable and pass it along as well.  Maybe in a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead like `dictionary.Add(nameof(x), x)`.

Comment: @juharr actually I'm trying to access the items through a `for i` loop, so a dictionary would be tricky... but I can use a `foreach(KeyValuePair)` loop instead with an `i` counter - thanks!

Comment: do note that dictionaries by nature are not ordered collections, if that matters.

Comment: Another option is a list of value tuples `List<(Name: string, Value: string)> list` and then you'd do `list.Add((nameof(x), x));` and `list[0].Name`.

Comment: I may have to do that, as iterating through a dictionary has just given me the issue  where I can't change the KeyValuePair value. It's get / read only once set :/

Comment: And it doesn't matter what the order is, because I'll be accessing / changing entries based on the dictionary key - however I now have the issue of not being able to change dictionary value when using a `foreach` loop. So I may have to try tuples instead so I can go back to a `for i` loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in the list is a *reference* to the string value `**` - there is nothing tying it back to `x` which is a *reference* to the same string.

`nameof` is a compile time facility.  Adding to a `List<T>` is a runtime facility which the compiler can't reasonably track those things for you.

Comment: I figured as much. I didn't know if there'd be a clever cache somewhere whenever lists were amended but by using a dictionary instead I can emulate that behaviour. Thanks!